# Canvas transformation transforms drawImage

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am currently working on a game (Purely a hobby) found at http://game.mersholm.dk
I got most things working out great (transformation, selection, movement, objects etc) But theres one nut of which i just cannot crack.

I am trying to add an isometric building using drawimage(experimenting). Ofcourse the image also undergoes a transformation due to the transformation matrix defined. This just makes the image twirl and rotate.

If i reset the matrix, draw the image and sets the matrix again it will break my screen to world cordinate calculations.

How would i go around adding isometric graphics to the world without twirling them with the matrix?

best regards.
Jonas

Comment: i'm not sure i understand your issue : if you save(), then draw the image with whatever transform, then restore(); nothing should be broken. ?

Comment: You sir, just saved my life! You should add that in an answer so i can deliever the points :)

Comment: Wow, right here, drinking my coffee and typing on my keyboard, i saved someone's life !! life is full of surprises !   :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to go when drawing an image with transform is this one :

- save the context.
- reset the context's transform.
- translate to the screen point where you will start drawing the image.
- apply the transform required for the image : rotate/scale/skew.
- draw the image at (0,0).
- restore the context.

In case you are confident with the previous state of the context, do not reset it.  But, then, if you don't reset the context -which is faster- just be sure to use world OR screen coordinates according to the current scale/transform.